# LinkOnceODRLinkage on Windows for global variables

Tags: windows, linker, llvm

I'm compiling two files with clang 6.0: `testA.c` and `testB.c`.

On both files I am running a custom compiler pass that inserts a zero-initialized global variable called `globalVarTest`. I set the linkage of such global variable to be `LinkOnceODRLinkage`.

Now, when I link `testA.c` and `testB.c` together (that is, the object files obtained by compiling them separately), the linker complains that there are multiple definitions of `globalVarTest`.

Isn't `LinkOnceODRLinkage` supposed to tell the linker that if both definitions match, the symbols is the same and it can therefore pick any of the two definitions when building the final executable?

UPDATE: 
The same procedure works on Linux. Is this a limitation of the Windows linker? I have been able to achieve the same effect using COMDAT sections but I wonder why LLVM is not using that mechanism automatically without me requiring to explicitly set COMDATS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the LLVM mailing list. Using `LinkOnceODRLinkage` does not work on Windows, even though it used to work in the past.

The best way to achieve the same effect is to explicitly use COMDAT sections. Apparently, this is what was happening automatically by setting `LinkOnceODRLinkage`, until the behavior changed.